# Why do I get a "method undefined" error for this method?

Tags: ruby, methods, undefined

I've defined the method startup before it gets called, but I'm still getting told that it hasn't been defined. I've tried looking for an answer but the only information I can find says the method needs to be defined before it's called, which I've clearly done! Code is below, startup is called right at the bottom. I know my code isn't complete, I just can't get past this undefined error.

```
# Ruby code file - All your code should be located between the comments provided.

# Add any additional gems and global variables here
# require 'sinatra'     # remove '#' character to run sinatra wen server

# Main class module
module OXs_Game
# Input and output constants processed by subprocesses. MUST NOT change.
NOUGHT = 0
CROSS = 1

class Game
    attr_reader :matrix, :input, :output, :player1, :player2, :winner
    attr_writer :matrix, :input, :output, :player1, :player2, :winner

    def initialize(input, output)
        @input = input
        @output = output
    end

    # Any code/methods aimed at passing the RSpect tests should be added below.
        def start
            @output.puts "Welcome to Noughts and Crosses!"
            @output.puts "Starting game..."
            @output.puts "Created by:Stephen Mitchell"
            @output.puts "Player 1: 0 and Player 2: 1"
        end

        def created_by
            return "myname"
        end

        def student_id
            return numberhere
        end

        def setplayer1
            @player1 = 0
        end

        def setplayer2
            @player2 = 1
        end

        def clearmatrix
            @matrix = ["_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_"]
        end

        def getmatrixvalue(n)
            @matrix[n]
        end

        def setmatrixvalue(i, v)
            @i = 1
            @v = "0"
            @matrix[i] = "0"            
        end

        def displaykey(matrix)
            @matrix = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]
            @output.puts "Table key:\n|#{matrix[0]}|#{matrix[1]}|#{matrix[2]}|\n|#{matrix[3]}|#{matrix[4]}|#{matrix[5]}|\n|#{matrix[6]}|#{matrix[7]}|#{matrix[8]}|\n"
        end

        def displaymatrix
            @matrix = ["_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_"]
            @output.puts "Table status:\n|#{matrix[0]}|#{matrix[1]}|#{matrix[2]}|\n|#{matrix[3]}|#{matrix[4]}|#{matrix[5]}|\n|#{matrix[6]}|#{matrix[7]}|#{matrix[8]}|\n"
        end

        def finish
            @output.puts "Finishing game..."
        end

        def displaymenu
            @output.puts "Menu: (1)Start | (2)New | (9)Exit\n"
        end

        def checkwinner
            if @matrix[0] = "0" && @matrix[1] = "0" && @matrix[2] = "0" then
                winner = 1
            elsif @matrix[3] = "0" && @matrix[4] = "0" && @matrix[5] = "0" then
                winner = 1
            elsif @matrix[6] = "0" && @matrix[7] = "0" && @matrix[8] = "0" then
                winner = 1
            elsif @matrix[0] = "0" && @matrix[3] = "0" && @matrix[6] = "0" then
                winner = 1
            elsif @matrix[1] = "0" && @matrix[4] = "0" && @matrix[7] = "0" then
                winner = 1  
            elsif @matrix[2] = "0" && @matrix[5] = "0" && @matrix[8] = "0" then
                winner = 1
            elsif @matrix[0] = "0" && @matrix[4] = "0" && @matrix[8] = "0" then
                winner = 1
            elsif @matrix[2] = "0" && @matrix[4] = "0" && @matrix[6] = "0" then
                winner = 1
            elsif @matrix[0] = "1" && @matrix[1] = "1" && @matrix[2] = "1" then
                winner = 2
            elsif @matrix[3] = "1" && @matrix[4] = "1" && @matrix[5] = "1" then
                winner = 2
            elsif @matrix[6] = "1" && @matrix[7] = "1" && @matrix[8] = "1" then
                winner = 2
            elsif @matrix[0] = "1" && @matrix[3] = "1" && @matrix[6] = "1" then
                winner = 2
            elsif @matrix[1] = "1" && @matrix[4] = "1" && @matrix[7] = "1" then
                winner = 2  
            elsif @matrix[2] = "1" && @matrix[5] = "1" && @matrix[8] = "1" then
                winner = 2
            elsif @matrix[0] = "1" && @matrix[4] = "1" && @matrix[8] = "1" then
                winner = 2
            elsif @matrix[2] = "1" && @matrix[4] = "1" && @matrix[6] = "1" then
                winner = 2  
            end
        end

    # Any code/methods aimed at passing the RSpect tests should be added above.

end
end

# Main program
module OXs_Game
@input = STDIN
@output = STDOUT
g = Game.new(@input, @output)
matrixkey = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]
matrix = ["_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_"]
playing = true
input = ""
option = 0
turn = 0

# Any code added to output the activity messages to the command line window should be added below.

def startup
    g.start
    g.displaykey(matrixkey)
    g.displaymatrix
    puts "Please select an option:"
    g.displaymenu
    menu_input = gets.chomp
end

def menu
    if menu_input == 1 then
        player1turn
    elsif menu_input == 2 then
        g.clearmatrix
        startup
    elsif menu_input == 9 then
        exit
    end
end

def player1turn
    g.displaymatrix
    puts "Player 1 to move."
    player1input = gets.chomp
    if player1input == 1 then
        @matrix[0] == "0"
    elsif player1input == 2 then
        @matrix[1] == "0"
    elsif player1input == 3 then
        @matrix[2] == "0"
    elsif player1input == 4 then
        @matrix[3] == "0"
    elsif player1input == 5 then
        @matrix[4] == "0"
    elsif player1input == 6 then
        @matrix[5] == "0"
    elsif player1input == 7 then
        @matrix[6] == "0"   
    elsif player1input == 8 then
        @matrix[7] == "0"   
    elsif player1input == 9 then
        @matrix[8] == "0"
    else
        puts "Invalid input, please try again."
        player1turn
    end

end 

startup 
# Any code added to output the activity messages to the command line window should be added above.
```

end

Comment: Where does the error occur? Don't expect people to sift through all that code...

Comment: It occurs when startup is called, at the end of the code. Like I said in my post.

Comment: Questions asking for help debugging a problem need the bare minimum code necessary to demonstrate the problem. Have you stripped this down to that point? Odds are good that the process of stripping it down will show you the problem.

Comment: A couple of problems: 1. `numberhere` in the method `student_id` is an undefined local variable or undefined method. 2. The local   variable `matrixkey` is not visible within `startup`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've define the `startup` method as an instance method a part of the `OXs_Game` module, but when you call it you are outside of the module.

Try removing your `OXs_Game` module (but leave all of the methods defined inside of it in the code).

You're going to have other issues with your code if you keep the `OXs_Game` module because you're using local variables inside of the module definition, but you whenever you use `def` to define a method it creates a new scope and you will no longer have access to local variables. The same is true when using `class` to define classes or `module` to define modules.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that jumped out is:

```
def setmatrixvalue(i, v)
    @i = 1
    @v = "0"
    @matrix[i] = "0"            
end
```

Why don't you do anything with `v`? And why don't you call the method?

Answer (score 0):

Here is working code.
There are 2 major changes I made.
In main program you declared local variables which were not accessible in `startup` and `menu` methods so i changed them to instance variables.

Secondly your `startup` method is instance method which cannot be called directly by  calling `startup` if you want to call it in that way you need to call it  by `OXs_Game::startup` . In this i code i changed `startup` method to class level method so it can be called directly. You can call it by `OXs_Game::startup` and leave it instance level as is in your code :)

```
module OXs_Game
 #Input and output constants processed by subprocesses. MUST NOT change.
NOUGHT = 0
CROSS = 1
class Game
    attr_reader :matrix, :input, :output, :player1, :player2, :winner
    attr_writer :matrix, :input, :output, :player1, :player2, :winner
    def initialize(input, output)
        @input = input
        @output = output
    end

#Any code/methods aimed at passing the RSpect tests should be added below.
    def start
        @output.puts "Welcome to Noughts and Crosses!"
        @output.puts "Starting game..."
        @output.puts "Created by:Stephen Mitchell"
        @output.puts "Player 1: 0 and Player 2: 1"
    end

    def created_by
        return "myname"
    end

    def student_id
        return numberhere
    end

    def setplayer1
        @player1 = 0
    end

    def setplayer2
        @player2 = 1
    end

    def clearmatrix
        @matrix = ["_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_"]
    end

    def getmatrixvalue(n)
        @matrix[n]
    end

    def setmatrixvalue(i, v)
        @i = 1
        @v = "0"
        @matrix[i] = "0"            
    end

    def displaykey(matrix)
        @matrix = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]
        @output.puts "Table key:\n|#{matrix[0]}|#{matrix[1]}|#{matrix[2]}|\n|#{matrix[3]}|#{matrix[4]}|#{matrix[5]}|\n|#{matrix[6]}|#{matrix[7]}|#{matrix[8]}|\n"
    end

    def displaymatrix
        @matrix = ["_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_"]
        @output.puts "Table status:\n|#{matrix[0]}|#{matrix[1]}|#{matrix[2]}|\n|#{matrix[3]}|#{matrix[4]}|#{matrix[5]}|\n|#{matrix[6]}|#{matrix[7]}|#{matrix[8]}|\n"
    end

    def finish
        @output.puts "Finishing game..."
    end

    def displaymenu
        @output.puts "Menu: (1)Start | (2)New | (9)Exit\n"
    end

    def checkwinner
        if @matrix[0] = "0" && @matrix[1] = "0" && @matrix[2] = "0" then
            winner = 1
        elsif @matrix[3] = "0" && @matrix[4] = "0" && @matrix[5] = "0" then
            winner = 1
        elsif @matrix[6] = "0" && @matrix[7] = "0" && @matrix[8] = "0" then
            winner = 1
        elsif @matrix[0] = "0" && @matrix[3] = "0" && @matrix[6] = "0" then
            winner = 1
        elsif @matrix[1] = "0" && @matrix[4] = "0" && @matrix[7] = "0" then
            winner = 1  
        elsif @matrix[2] = "0" && @matrix[5] = "0" && @matrix[8] = "0" then
            winner = 1
        elsif @matrix[0] = "0" && @matrix[4] = "0" && @matrix[8] = "0" then
            winner = 1
        elsif @matrix[2] = "0" && @matrix[4] = "0" && @matrix[6] = "0" then
            winner = 1
        elsif @matrix[0] = "1" && @matrix[1] = "1" && @matrix[2] = "1" then
            winner = 2
        elsif @matrix[3] = "1" && @matrix[4] = "1" && @matrix[5] = "1" then
            winner = 2
        elsif @matrix[6] = "1" && @matrix[7] = "1" && @matrix[8] = "1" then
            winner = 2
        elsif @matrix[0] = "1" && @matrix[3] = "1" && @matrix[6] = "1" then
            winner = 2
        elsif @matrix[1] = "1" && @matrix[4] = "1" && @matrix[7] = "1" then
            winner = 2  
        elsif @matrix[2] = "1" && @matrix[5] = "1" && @matrix[8] = "1" then
            winner = 2
        elsif @matrix[0] = "1" && @matrix[4] = "1" && @matrix[8] = "1" then
            winner = 2
        elsif @matrix[2] = "1" && @matrix[4] = "1" && @matrix[6] = "1" then
            winner = 2  
        end
    end

# Any code/methods aimed at passing the RSpect tests should be added above.

end
end

module OXs_Game
@input = STDIN
@output = STDOUT
@g = Game.new(@input, @output)
@matrixkey = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]
@matrix = ["_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_"]
@playing = true
@input = ""
@option = 0
@turn = 0

#Any code added to output the activity messages to the command line window should be added below.

def self.startup
    @g.start
    @g.displaykey(@matrixkey)
    @g.displaymatrix
    puts "Please select an option:"
    @g.displaymenu
    menu_input = gets.chomp
end

def menu
    if menu_input == 1 then
        player1turn
    elsif menu_input == 2 then
        @g.clearmatrix
        startup
    elsif menu_input == 9 then
        exit
    end
end

def player1turn
    @g.displaymatrix
    puts "Player 1 to move."
    player1input = gets.chomp
    if player1input == 1 then
        @matrix[0] == "0"
    elsif player1input == 2 then
        @matrix[1] == "0"
    elsif player1input == 3 then
        @matrix[2] == "0"
    elsif player1input == 4 then
        @matrix[3] == "0"
    elsif player1input == 5 then
        @matrix[4] == "0"
    elsif player1input == 6 then
        @matrix[5] == "0"
    elsif player1input == 7 then
        @matrix[6] == "0"   
    elsif player1input == 8 then
        @matrix[7] == "0"   
    elsif player1input == 9 then
        @matrix[8] == "0"
    else
        puts "Invalid input, please try again."
        player1turn
    end

end 
startup
end
```